# Browser puts non-versioned file instead of versioned file first.

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, browser, server

I'm using the wp_enqueue_style() function for versioning my master.css-file, in order to prevent browser caching.

This works, a new version is created each time, however ... my browser keeps putting a "non-versioned" copy first (without new changes) ... where does this non-versioned copy come from? What am I doing wrong? Both files point to the same directory on the server, however, there's only one file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot this without seeing your code, but it seems likely that you've accidentally enqueued your CSS file twice. Do they show the same file handle name? This is the value that appears as the "id" in the source code (before the "-css").

For example:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='file-handle-css'  href='https://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/master.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`

If the file handles are different in the versioned and non-versioned files, you can search your source code for the file handle used in the non-versioned copy of the file, then comment it out.

If the file handles are the same, then try changing it when enqueuing the versioned copy, then checking the source again to see if they now differ.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, this is not the problem. The CSS file is only enqueued once, and I don't see any other files that might cause the problem. If I check the "sources" tab, it says the server contains both a normal master.css file, and besides a master.css?ver=... file, where I just want the last one of course ...